# How to debug/troubleshoot SQL Server stored proc type error with many parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, search

I've looked around quite a bit. The questions I've seen here that involve the SSMS 2008+ debug tool have not been helpful to me because executing the proc fails as soon as you step into it. A type mismatch that can't be implicitly converted will throw an error, and you won't know which parameter was to blame.

Here is an abbreviated example:

Your proc starts like this and goes on to over 100 parameters:

```
USE [Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[reallycomplicatedprocedure]
@input1 varchar(100),
@input2 varchar(100),
@input3 uniqueidentifier,
@input4 varchar(100),
@input5 varchar(100),
@input6 varchar(100),
@input7 vuniqueidentifier,
@input8 varchar(100),
@input9 varchar(100),
@input10 varchar(100),
@input11 varchar(100),
@input12 uniqueidentifier,
@input13 datetime,
@input14 varchar(100),
@input15 varchar(100),
@input16 binary(255),
@input17 varchar(100),
@input18 varchar(100),
@input19 varchar(100),
@input20 varchar(100),
. . . .

as
begin 
print 'foo'
end
```

And you have a web app calling the proc like this:

```
exec reallycomplicatedprodecure 'thisisavarchar','','0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0','','thisisanothervalue','','This is some company name,'','', '', 'this is more information', '',getdate(13), '','The latte dah coffe comapny','','','','thisisastring','' . . . .
```

So we have a big unreadable mess that, so far, I have not been able to find a way to deal with well inside of SSMS and the debug tools that are available.

I came up with a process for handling this today that I am going to post as an answer, but I really hope that other people have a better one. I hope that mine is the worst. :)

Comment: At around about the point where I'm adding the tenth parameter, I start to think that something is wrong. How on earth do you get up to one hundred? Usually there's a better way of structuring so much data (e.g. as one XML parameter that conforms to a good XSD that tooling can help you to generate/correct, or table valued parameters, etc)

Comment: *shrug* You don't always get to choose what you have to support. Sometimes you show up at a job and someone says, "Here. This is broken. Fix it."  I don't mean to suggest that this is a good design that people perpetuate. I just mean for it to be helpful for others in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into any of this, here's a quick thing to check: NULL != ''. If you are having type errors in this situation, you might be passing empty strings to types like uniqueidentifier or binary. '' is not an acceptable substitute for NULL. If you mean NULL, say so when your web service calls your proc.

After that has been taken care of . . . feel free to continue. My problem today involved both the NULL/'' thing I mentioned above and some other less obvious type mismatches. But I thought it would be useful to point out the easy fix sooner rather than later.

The first thing I did was to create a new proc without any foo. Just get the parameters done and print 'params loaded' so I didn't get any undeclared variable errors from what I am about to do next. So I have:

```
USE [Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[paramTest]
@input1 varchar(100),
@input2 varchar(100),
@input3 uniqueidentifier,
@input4 varchar(100),
@input5 varchar(100),
@input6 varchar(100),
@input7 vuniqueidentifier,
@input8 varchar(100),
@input9 varchar(100),
@input10 varchar(100),
@input11 varchar(100),
@input12 uniqueidentifier,
@input13 datetime,
@input14 varchar(100),
@input15 varchar(100),
@input16 binary(255),
@input17 varchar(100),
@input18 varchar(100),
@input19 varchar(100),
@input20 varchar(100),
. . . .

as
begin 
print 'params loaded'
end
```

Then you take your favorite text editor and get the exec statement so that it has one line per argument. Find/replace ',' with ',\n' or whatever syntax works for your editor. Bottom line is that it should look like this:

```
exec paramTest 
    'thisisavarchar',
    '',
    '0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0',
    '',
    'thisisanothervalue',
    '',
    'This is some company name,
    '',
    '',
     '',
     'this is more information',
     '',
    getdate(13),
     '',
    'The latte dah coffe comapny',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'thisisastring',
    ''
```

So this gives me a vertical list of params and inputs that I can work with to find the culprit(s). I'm not sure what the formal name for this kind of search algorithm is or if it even has one. It's not a sorted list, so it's not a real binary search. When I was in junior high, I used to work for the local university fixing the Macs they had. System 7 was a wonderful/horrible place because of extensions. We used to do what we called a split-half search to figure out which extensions were crashing a given machine. That's what I'm doing here.

Comment out the top half of the params. Note how many lines are being commented out. Comment out the same number of lines in your exec query. Execute and look for the same type error. So it looks like this:

Proc:

```
--@input1 varchar(100),
--@input2 varchar(100),
--@input3 uniqueidentifier,
--@input4 varchar(100),
--@input5 varchar(100),
--@input6 varchar(100),
--@input7 vuniqueidentifier,
--@input8 varchar(100),
--@input9 varchar(100),
--@input10 varchar(100),
@input11 varchar(100),
@input12 uniqueidentifier,
@input13 datetime,
@input14 varchar(100),
@input15 varchar(100),
@input16 binary(255),
@input17 varchar(100),
@input18 varchar(100),
@input19 varchar(100),
@input20 varchar(100),
```

And the exec:

```
    --'thisisavarchar',
    --'',
    --'0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0',
    --'',
    --'thisisanothervalue',
    --'',
    --'This is some company name,
    --'',
    --'',
    -- '',
     'this is more information',
     '',
    getdate(13),
     '',
    'The latte dah coffe comapny',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'thisisastring',
    ''
```

The way this works from here is obvious. If you still get the error, the culprit is in the remaining half of the uncommented params. In not, comment out the half that are active an uncomment the top half and split them, searching half, then half, then half, however many times you need to in order to deal with a manageable number of params.

My experience today was that getting down to 12 or params at a time allowed me to find the offending type mismatches very easily.

If you start with ~200 parameters, it's 4 search iterations to get to something manageable. If you takes notes to keep track of yourself, it's documentable and reproducible. Once I decided on this approach, it took me maybe 30 minutes or so to nail down the problems.

But a) I think there are probably better solutions, and b) this could probably be written as a troubleshooting function that does this for you. Because, unfortunately, I'm afraid this is more common a problem than I want it to be.